# Finding the foci of an ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Let's say we have the following figure
[image]

where $ζ$ is the major axis, $Ε$ is one foci, $ε$ is a tangent and $Μ$ a point of the plane. Also, I don't know how to call $κ$ in English, but it's the circle with center Ε..

Can someone tell me how I can find where $E'$, the second foci, is on the axis $ζ$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's the circle with center E" : how do define its radius ?

Comment: It is a very common circle in ellipses, I just don't know how it's called it in English, sorry. It's radius is the common number $2a$, the distance between the vertices of the ellipse. I just can't find out how,  given these facts, and no number, we can find where to "put" the other foci $Ε'$.

Comment: The ellipse is to go through the point M?

Comment: No no, it's just a random point in the plane. It's not part of the ellipse.

Comment: I can think of a trial and error method, which I'm not sure is correct. You have to use the reflective properties of the ellipse (which is why you are given a tangent line to the ellipse) and the fact that the radius of the circle is $2a$, giving us $a$. Let $c$ be the distance a focus is away from the center.  Then since the radius is $2a$, the other focus would have to be $2(a-c)$ inwards from the intersection of $\kappa$ and $\zeta$. The problem is we don't know $c$. Therefore we use the reflective properties. From $E$, draw a random line segment to any point $P$ on $\varepsilon$. If $P$

Comment: were a point on the ellipse, then you could measure the angle that the line segment makes with $\epsilon$. Use that angle to draw a line segment back from $P$ to $\zeta$. Then, you would, from $E$ and our supposed $E'$, find $c$. From our new piece of information, then $E'$ better satisfy $2(a - c)$. If not, then our chosen point $P$ was incorrect. I believe this is a valid guess and check procedure but I'm not sure

Comment: This sounds correct. Thank you very much! One question only. Maybe it should be $2a - c$ and not $2(a-c)$? Not sure, its late and im tired. :D

Comment: I see what you did. You did something like $2a - (2a - c)$ to get $c$? But when you subtract one number $(2a - c)$, from another $2a$, the result $c$ is the distance between the two. We don't want the distance between the intersection point and the focus to be $c$. We want the distance between the center of the ellipse and the focus $E'$ to be $c$. From a diagram I drew, from $E$ you go out $c$ to the center of the ellipse, out another $c$ to $E'$, then out a distance $(a-c)$ to the edge of the ellipse. From here, we have to go another $(a-c)$ out to the circle. That's what I think at least

Comment: Ah yeah you are right. By the way, georg gave an answer below. Do you have any idea why the radius $a$ circle is going to pass from the center of the ellipse?

Comment: He may have figured something out, but I don't follow his diagram at the moment. The center of the circle should be at $E$, with radius $2a$. But in his diagram, he drew a circle of radius $a$ centered on the tangent line. In other words according to him, you should completely forget about your diagram. If his work is true, then he found a very interesting property of ellipse. Given the line $\zeta$, a single focal point $E$, and any tangent line: from $E$ go to the closest point on the tangent line (the green dot). This point may or may not be on the ellipse. However drawing a circle there

Comment: of radius $a$ will show you the center of the ellipse. This is very interesting if true

Comment: His method works for at least one tangent line, the "vertical" tangent line. Draw a normal ellipse "horizontally". Next to one of the foci, draw a vertical tangent line. Now the closest point from that focus to the vertical tangent line is that point on the ellipse a distance $a$ away from the center. Drawing a circle here of radius $a$, does show you where the center of the ellipse is. Very interesting

Comment: I have no idea why or how this works, I'm totally new to this stuff! I hope he will answer my questions below so we can find out how this works exactly. Thanks for your help anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

[image]

J = center of ellipse

Radius of circle = a

E1 '= second focus

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you give me a bit more help? How did you know where J must be?

Comment: You created a circle of radius $a$ and center the projection of $E$ on the tangent. But why does this circle pass from J? Sorry for silly questions, im new to this stuff

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand English for a reasonable conversation. It's actually the opposite: A circle with a center in J with a radius 'a' passes the center of the focus projection on all tangents of the ellipse. That's why I determined point J.

Comment: It's ok, don't worry, I understood it perfectly now. Thank you very much for the help, have a good night.